# Short question: How is $C^1(K)$ defined for a compact set $K$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, compactness

Let $K\subset\mathbb R^d$ be compact. Then how is $C^1(K)$ defined? I've seen this at many places, but no one seems to care about the problems at the boundary of $K$.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means "the set of restrictions of functions that are defined on an open set containing $K$, and that are $C^1$ on the open set".

I think I remember from differential geometry courses that whenever $K$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the intrinsic definition of $C^1(K)$ coincides with this one, therefore it is a "good definition".

Note that any $C^1$ function in the above sense is obviously $C^1$ in @Surb's sense. For $d = 1$, the definitions agree: let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous, $C^1$ on the interior of the interval, and such that $j(a) := \lim_{x\to a} f'(x)$ and $j(b) :=\lim_{x\to b} f'(x)$ exist. Then define $g$ as $f$ on $[a,b]$ and, on $(a-1,a)$ to be $t \mapsto (t-a)j(a) + f(a)$ and on $(b, b+1)$ to be $t \mapsto (t-b)j(b) + f(b)$. Then it is easy to show that $g$ is $C^1$ on $(a-1,b+1)$. I don't know if the same is true in higher dimensions.

Comment: I don't think it is. Therefore, your definition seems a little too strict in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem comes from the derivative on the boundary of $K$. Suppose that $\text{int}(K)$ is a domain.  Normally, $f\in \mathcal C^1(K)$ means that $f\in \mathcal C^0(K)\cap \mathcal C^{1}(\text{int}(K))$ s.t. for all $u\in Bd(K)$, the limit $$\lim_{\substack{x\to u \\ x\in \text{int}(K)}}f'(x)$$ exist. I let you determine what means $f'$ in this context (it's the gradient if $f:K\to \mathbb R$, or the Jacobian if $f:K\to \mathbb R^m$ for some $m\geq 2$).

---

So, for $d=1$, then $K=[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb R$, $a<b$ and $f:K\to \mathbb R$. So, namely $f\in \mathcal C^1([a,b])$ means that $f\in \mathcal C^0([a,b])\cap \mathcal C^1((a,b))$ s.t. $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to b^-}f'(x),$$ exists.

Comment: Thanks. But would this imply that the directional derivatives of $f$ into directions that point into the domain, exist?

Comment: of course... but if you are in the domain, there should not have any ambiguities... so your remark/question is not clear...

Comment: I think it's clear. Of course, there are no ambiguities in the domain. My question again: assume that $f\in C^1(K)$ as in your definition, where $K = \overline\Omega$. Let $x\in\partial\Omega$ and let $y\in\mathbb R^d$ such that $x+ty\in\Omega$ for $t\in (0,\epsilon)$. Does then $D_yf(x)$ exist (the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $y$)?

Comment: To make things simple : take $K=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ and $f:K\to \mathbb R$. You can't define $f'(2)$ in any way...

Comment: I rather thought of $K = \overline{\Omega}$ with some domain $\Omega$ (as you assumed in your answer). The last $K$ you gave me is not of this kind. It seems to me, you still haven't understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

$$C^m(\bar{\Omega}) := \{ f \in C^m(\Omega); \: \forall |\alpha| \leq m, \exists \: g^{\alpha} \in C({\bar{\Omega}}) \: s.t. \: \partial^{\alpha}f = g^{\alpha}|_{\Omega}       \}$$

ln other words, $C^m(\bar{\Omega})$ consists of all functions $f \in C^m(\Omega)$ that, together with all their partial
derivatives $\partial^{\alpha}f \:, 1 \leq \alpha \leq m $ possess continuous extensions to $\bar{\Omega}$ or equivalently, such that,
at each point $x_0 \in \partial \Omega, \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} 
 \partial^{\alpha}f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R} \:, \: 0 \leq \alpha \leq m $ or equivalently, when $\Omega$ is bounded, if each function $\partial^{\alpha} f, \: 0 \leq \alpha \leq m$ is uniformly continuous in $\Omega$. 
Source: Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis (section 1.18) by Philippe G. Ciarlet